# Airborne geophysical survey in steep and undulating terrain. What is more important, energy conservation or orienting lines wrt to geology and why?

Tags: geology, geophysics, minerals, geomagnetism, mining

I am trying to design a cost and energy efficient aerial survey and have come up against the question, 'do we have to fly straight lines perpenducular to geology?' as not doing so could make for a more energy efficient program.

Does anyone have a good explanation on why geophysical surveys (particularly aeromag) are flown in parallel lines perpendicular to known features?

Is there any reason why you couldn't fly your survey along Topographic contours where terrain is very steep and undulating to reduce the energy requirements on your survey?

Comment: In most [all?] surveys the sensors will have a higher resolution along the flight line than the spacing  between flight lines, so flying across strike gives the greatest precision in locating boundaries. If flown parallel to strike the precision would be limited to the spacing between lines.

Comment: Thanks @AndyM. Great point, do you know of any references I can look at regarding survey design and experimentation?